# Characterizations of Nilpotent Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, math-history, nilpotent-groups

There are several characterizations of finite nilpotent groups ([they are, as in wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_group#Properties)):

1. $G$ is  (finite) nilpotent group.
2. Normalizer of every proper subgroup is bigger than the subgroup.
3. Every maximal subgroup is normal.
4. $G$ is direct product of Sylow subgroups.

The equivalence 
$ (1) \Longleftrightarrow (3)$
is often attributed to Wielandt, whereas, other equivalences are not attributed to anyone.

I wonder to see, who obtained these equivalent conditions. 
Can one give the historical reference to these equivalences?

Also, the theorem 
$$\mbox{the upper and lower central series of a group have same length}$$
gives a definition of nilpotent group with its nilpotency class. Philip Hall said in a paper that this remarkable theorem appears in the Speiser's book on Group Theory (~ 1909,very earlier book on the subject). Then, is this a theorem of Speiser, or it was known before him?